# Scipy. interpolate griddata cubic spline returning nan instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am performing a cubic spline using scipy.interpolate griddata. I tested some values and a number of nans were returned. I have given an example in my code. How can I changed the code in order to produce a value and not nan?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

y = [164,166,168,172,173,181,185,189,
             189,191,196,197,198,201,214,218,
             223,224,227,230,231,232,237,253,
             257,257,258,262,266]

z = [0.68,0.95,0.44,0.68,0.93,0.69,0.94,
             1.55,0.94,1.53,1.85,0.52,1.53,1.83,
             0.98,1.53,0.77,1.82,1.56,2.43,1.01,
             1.82,0.15,2.41,1.84,0.39,0.64,1.56,
             2.39]

x = [100,250,400,550,700,850,1000,1150,1300,
             1450,1600,1750,1900,2050,2200,2350,2500,
             2650,2800,2950,3100,3250,3400,3550,3700,
             3850,4000,4150,4300]

xi = np.linspace(100,4300)
yi = np.linspace(164,266)

zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='cubic')

print(griddata((x,y),z,(3128,265), method='cubic'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior: [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) only interpolates **inside the convex hull** of the given points. In your case the input points (blue crosses) cover just a small area (surrounded by the black line) and your point (3128,265) (orange dot) is outside this convex hull:
[image]

So your code is OK, you just need to provide more input data (x,y,z) to cover the area you want to interpolate in.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking something like this but couldn't explain it clearly in the question. What is a better method to use other than griddata?

Comment: @cosmicnoise extrapolation is terribly dangerous, because more often than not it creates nonsense data. Only extrapolate if you have a very clear idea of what the data should look like outside the interpolation region (the convex hull of input points). You can either use `fill_value` in `griddata` to get a constant non-nan value outside, or use `'nearest'` interpolation which always chooses the closest datapoint. Otherwise you might be better off by fitting a 2d function on your data (think linear regression, just more generally), and using that to query points.